# Add elements to uilistbox programmatically

Tags: matlab, matlab-gui

I'm playing with MATLAB GUIs and I want to add elements to a listBox as my program generate them. I have a function that generates data and I want to put the "Name" of those data inside a list box. Here's my function:

```
function [ birdInfo, trackBuff ] = saveParabolaOnFramesPlot( birdInfo, trackBuff , f, listbox)
```

Here's how I actually set the element, but it fails with the following error:

> There is no String property on the ListBox class
>        set(listbox, 'String', stringOfField)

The value of `stringOfField` is just a string.

Here's how I call this function from AppDesigner Code View:

```
[app.birdInfo, app.trackBuff ] = saveParabolaOnFramesPlot( app.birdInfo, app.trackBuff , app.birdInfo.aFrame, app.JumpListListBox);
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'String'` is the property that is used by the `uicontrol` objects which are different than the ones created by AppDesigner. Based on the documentation for [`uilistbox`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uilistbox.html#input_argument_namevalue_Items), you'll want to set the `Items` property instead

Also if you're wanting to *append* a new item, you'll want to get the current list of items (a cell array of strings) and append your new item before assigning it.

```
currentItems = get(listbox, 'Items');
newitems = cat(2, currentItems, stringOfField);
set(listbox, 'Items', newitems)
```

Or more simply:

```
listboxt.Items{end+1} = stringOfField;
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem. I swear I've readed the doc, but maybe I missed this important step. ^_^